# Async problems in Node.Js - how to perform a sequence of actions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I need to perform a series of actions on a variable, where the output of the previous action would be the input of the next one.

Also, there is a possibility that at each step the whole process aborts in case the input is not well formed.

I know this could be done with the callback functions, but I have so many steps it's turning into a mess.

Does anybody know of a good solution I could use to avoid this? Just a module, which helps perform actions sequentially? Or another technique?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should change the approach your taken and solve it with Node async model in mind

Comment: Q might help https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: @Dalorzo what would you suggest? Using promises? Having 10 steps of nested functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like [async.waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) might be what you're looking for.

As far as aborting early goes, `async` doesn't have an easy way to do this, but what I've generally done is call the callback with a "fake" Error instance and then in the final callback, I check for a "fake" Error vs real error (usually I tack on some property like 'err.abort = true;` and check for that).

Comment: You are my savior! Thank you so much, @mscdex. I've been fighting with it for 12 hours and what you suggested worked like magic!

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). You can use [async.whilst](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) or [async.until](https://github.com/caolan/async#untiltest-fn-callback)

```
var count = 0;

async.whilst(
    function () { return count < 5; },
    function (callback) {
        count++;
        setTimeout(callback, 1000);
    },
    function (err) {
        // 5 seconds have passed
    }
);
```

the first function is used for conditional check. the second function is actually logic, you can save the result and reuse it as the new input.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting whilst. While it doesn't do what I need it's a very good idea for another part of the code.